# Get the value of a custom field of a WordPress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created one custom field in WordPress' edit post section, and am able to save the value by following this posts: [Wordpress - Adding custom field to the post screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850901/wordpress-adding-custom-field-to-the-post-screen).

I'm able to retrieve the posts of the specific category, but I'm unable to retrieve the value of custom field.

[image]

As seen in image above, there is a custom post field at highlighted at the top left. The other highlighted field is to show that the post belongs to the "Portfolio" category.

Here is the code I used to retrieve the posts of the category "Portfolio"

```
<?php 
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'category_name' => 'Portfolio', 
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'order' => 'DESC'
)); 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    $the_query->the_post();
?>

<p>The title: <?php the_title(); ?></p>
<p> custome value: <?php get_post_meta( $post_ID, '_ssb_portfolio_url', true); ?> </p>
<p>The Content: <?php the_content(); ?></p>

<?php 
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I'm able to get the value of the title of the post and the content of the post, but not custom field value. What wrong in my code?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/114055/25035

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [get_post_custom( $post_id )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom)

In your case

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    $custom = get_post_custom( get_the_ID() ); ?>
```

Then `$custom` is an array of your custom fields

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the post's custom field in the same SQL call that the post's query ? (for optimisation)

Comment: I would also like to know, if it can be done with the initial query for posts?